# CombineLatestStream.combine2 combiner never gets called

Tags: flutter, objectbox, rxdart

I'm trying to combine two streams of my entities, `Category` and `Menu`.
I tried this way but it seems like the combiner never gets executed (notice there was `print` statements inside, it never prints).

I'm very sure I properly followed the sample snippet on [rxdart's API docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream/combine2.html). And able to show the the data by directly binding the `stream()` function into the observable (`.obs`), but I need to combine it to be able to refresh `Category`'s `menus` property every time I add, edit, or remove them.

1. I tried to rebuild the app (`ctrl + shift + F5`)
2. Switching from `CombineLatestStream.combine2` to `Rx.combineLatest2`
3. Performing `flutter clean` and `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` and re-run the app.

But it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

I'm using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) as my state management and [ObjectBox](https://docs.objectbox.io/) as my database.
`category_repository.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' hide Category;
import 'package:myapp/app/data/entities/category.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app/data/entities/menu.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app/data/repositories/menu_repository.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app/services/objectbox_service.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class CategoryRepository {
  final _box = ObjectBoxService.instance.store.box<Category>();

  Stream<List<Category>> stream() {
    debugPrint('streaming List<Category>....');
    return _box.query().watch().map((query) => query.find());
  }

  Stream<List<CategoryWithMenus>> streamWithMenus() {
    debugPrint('combining streams into List<CategoryWithMenus>....');

    final categoriestream = stream();
    final menustream = MenuRepository().stream();

    final combined = CombineLatestStream.combine2(
      categoriestream,
      menustream,
      (List<Category> categories, List<Menu> menus) {
        debugPrint('mapping...'); // this never printed out
        final idToCat = {for (var cat in categories) cat.id: cat};
        final ids = idToCat.keys;

        final cidToMenus = <int, List<Menu>>{};
        for (var men in menus) {
          cidToMenus.putIfAbsent(men.category.targetId, () => []).add(men);
        }

        final result = [
          for (var id in ids)
            CategoryWithMenus(idToCat[id]!, cidToMenus[id] ?? []),
        ];

        for (var r in result) {
          debugPrint(r.toString());
        }

        return result;
      },
    );

    debugPrint('streams combined...');
    debugPrint('streaming List<CategoryWithMenus>....');

    return combined;
  }
}

class CategoryWithMenus {
  final Category category;
  final List<Menu> menus;

  CategoryWithMenus(this.category, this.menus);
}
```

`menu_repository.dart`

```dart
import 'package:myapp/app/data/entities/menu.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app/services/objectbox_service.dart';

class MenuRepository {
  final _box = ObjectBoxService.instance.store.box<Menu>();

  Stream<List<Menu>> stream() {
    print('streaming List<Menu>....');
    return _box.query().watch().map((query) => query.find());
  }
}
```

`category.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app/data/entities/menu.dart';
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';

@Entity()
class Category {
  int id = 0;
  String name = 'Unknown';
  int labelColor = Colors.purple.shade900.value;

  @Backlink('category')
  final menus = ToMany<Menu>();
}
```

`menu.dart`

```dart
import 'package:myapp/app/data/entities/addition.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app/data/entities/category.dart';
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';

@Entity()
class Menu {
  int id = 0;
  String name = 'Unknown';
  double price = 0.0;

  final category = ToOne<Category>();

  @Backlink('menu')
  final additions = ToMany<Addition>();
}
```

`home_controller.dart`

```dart
import 'package:myapp/app/data/entities/category.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app/data/entities/menu.dart';
import 'package:myapp/app/data/repositories/category_repository.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  HomeController({
    required CategoryRepository categoryRepository,
  }) : _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;

  final CategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
  final categories = <CategoryWithMenus>[].obs;
  final activeCategory = Rxn<CategoryWithMenus>();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    final cstream = _categoryRepository.streamWithMenus();
    categories.bindStream(cstream);
    print(categories.length);
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

`debug console`

```bash
Restarted application in 1,213ms.
[GETX] Instance "ObjectBoxService" has been created
[GETX] Instance "ObjectBoxService" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /home
[GETX] Instance "HomeController" has been created
flutter: combining streams into Stream<List<CategoryWithMenus>>....
flutter: streaming List<Category>....
flutter: streaming List<Menu>....
flutter: streams combined...
flutter: streaming List<CategoryWithMenus>....
flutter: 0
[GETX] Instance "HomeController" has been initialized
```

**EDIT**

I have created and shown 10 records from a form screen before switching from direct `stream()` binding to `rxdart`.

Comment: `CombineLatestStream.combine2` emits first event if both streams emit their data - most likely at least one of them did not do that

Comment: Alright I'll try to test it by inserting new record then...

Comment: Still doesn't work.. I got the new data persisted though.. Should I post my form implementation too?

Comment: how do you know that both streams emitted at least one event?

Comment: I didn't, but I know the data was persisted cuz I logged it right after inserting by using the returned `id` of the ObjectBox's `put` method.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem! I have to set `triggerImmediately` to `true` in every `watch` function inside my `stream()`.

Thanks @pskink for pointing me out about event emission. It works now.

```dart
class CategoryRepository {
  final _box = ObjectBoxService.instance.store.box<Category>();

  Stream<List<Category>> stream() {
    debugPrint('streaming List<Category>....');
    return _box
        .query()
        .watch(triggerImmediately: true)
        .map((query) => query.find());
  }

  ...
}

class MenuRepository {
  final _box = ObjectBoxService.instance.store.box<Menu>();

  Stream<List<Menu>> stream() {
    print('streaming List<Menu>....');
    return _box
        .query()
        .watch(triggerImmediately: true)
        .map((query) => query.find());
  }
}
```